# get two ui-sliders pass values to ajax when one change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I want to pass data from two ui-sliders (more in the future) to my php-server with ajax. I have the code below. The problem is that I need some help to understand how I get on hold on the value of the slider that the user doesn't change. The first slider only send one value to genData.php. The second slider send two values "data: {'slider2': ui.value, 'slider':2}," but I want to change "2" to the value of slider 1. Any good ideas? Feel free to change the structure as well.

```
<html>
     <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui1103/css/start/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo1">Value of slider 1.</div>
    <div id="foo2">Value of slider 2.</div>
    <div id="foo3">value1*value2.</div>
    <div id="scrollbar"></div><br><br>
    <div id="scrollbar2"></div>
</body>
<script src="jqueryui1103/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryui1103/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#scrollbar').slider({
            value: 35,
            max: 36,
            range: "max",
            animate: true,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $('#scrollbar').slider('value', ui.value);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'genData.php',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: {'slider': ui.value},
                    success: function(fromphp) {
                        $('#foo1').html(fromphp.foo1);
                        $('#foo2').html(fromphp.foo2);
                        $('#foo3').html(fromphp.foo1);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $('#scrollbar2').slider({
            value: 3,
            max: 50,
            range: "max",
            animate: true,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $('#scrollbar2').slider('value', ui.value);
                /** var test = ($("#slider").slider("value")); */
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'genData.php',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: {'slider2': ui.value, 'slider':2},
                    success: function(fromphp) {
                        $('#foo1').html(fromphp.foo1);
                        $('#foo2').html(fromphp.foo2);
                        $('#foo3').html(fromphp.foo1);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You should consider refactoring those ajax calls into one function and calling that instead of having two identical ajax functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value by doing the following

```
  $("#scrollbar").slider( "option", "value" );
```

Here is a complete working solution
http://jsfiddle.net/yALMx/74/

Ive refactored it into one ajax call and it gets the values of both sliders